# CRUD edit model data now shown

Tags: php, html, jquery, cron

I got some problem using jquery for displaying existing data when crud edit button is click. The bootstrap popup windows is shown if I remove  $('#catid).val(data[0]); and $('#catname).val(data[1]); from the code.If add back the code, the bootstrap popup windows not showing without error. Not sure it is the script problem or the form problem. Anyone can help! Thanks.

```
enter code here
 
<!-- Edit Model -->
<div class="modal fade" id="editcatmodel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
       <input type="hidden" name="catid" id="catid">
       
       <div class="form-group">
        <label>Category Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="catname" id="catname" class="form-control">
      </div>

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">save</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->


 <!-- Main screen display the crud data with edit button -->
<div class="container">
    <table class="table">
<thead>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Action</th>
</thead>
<tbody> 
    <?php
    require_once 'source/db_connect.php';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM category";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            //output data of each row
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            
    ?>
    
 <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['catid']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['catname']; ?>  </td>
    <td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary editcatbtn">edit</button>  </td>
    </tr>   
    
    <?php       }
        }
    ?>

<!-- script display the modal -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$(' .editcatbtn').on('click', function() {
    $('#editcatmodel').modal('show');
         $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
             var data = $tr.children("td").map(function() {
                return $(this).text();
             }).get();
             console.log(data);
            $('#catid).val(data[0]); 
            $('#catname).val(data[1]); 
             
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: You tried to fix this:
            `$('#catid).val(data[0]);`  to  `$('#catid').val(data[0]);`
            `$('#catname).val(data[1]);` to    `$('#catname').val(data[1]);`

Comment: Sorry its my typing mistake. Thanks a lot!

Comment: NP, give it a try if it's working.